# Can I populate Session Variable with a query result?

Tags: php, mysql

Is populating PHP session variables with a query result possible - if so,
what is the **proper syntax**?
**My code:**-

```
session_start();
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $_SESSION['userid'] = $rows['id'];
   $_SESSION['firstname'] = $rows['firstname'];
   $_SESSION['lastname'] = $rows['lastname'];
}
```

I tried this code above with no positive result.

Comment: Yes, its possible but you are assigning values in loop you only last values will be assigned to session

Comment: @urfusion is right, you can easily assign the value,  you need to create multiple array...

Comment: But would this work if I indicate "WHERE email='$myusername' and password='$mypassword' LIMIT 1"...? in the initial query (retrieved via GET POST)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get single row then update your query and simple use this code

```
session_start();
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$_SESSION['userid'][] = $rows['id'];
$_SESSION['firstname'][] = $rows['firstname'];
$_SESSION['lastname'][] = $rows['lastname'];
```

and if you multiple data then use this code

```
session_start();
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $_SESSION['userid'][] = $rows['id'];
    $_SESSION['firstname'][] = $rows['firstname'];
    $_SESSION['lastname'][] = $rows['lastname'];
}
```

and if you want to store total row data then use this code

```
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$_SESSION['data'] = $rows;
```

this is another method which first store your data in variable then assign to session

```
session_start();
$your_data='';
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $user_info['userid'] = $rows['id'];
    $user_info['firstname'] = $rows['firstname'];
    $user_info['lastname'] = $rows['lastname'];
    $your_data[]=$user_info;

}
$_SESSION['your_data'] = $your_data;
```

hope it will help you

Comment: Can you illustrate how I would place the session variable into a local variable on a future page (i.e. $user_info = $user['userinfo'] OR $user_info = $_SESSION['user'] OR ???) Thank you - d

Comment: print_r($_SESSION['your_data']);
this you will understand which value need to use and $_SESSION['your_data']['userid'][index]; need to use

Comment: Gives me the results of the array - but still a bit confused... I simply want to put one of the values in a local variable. Logic along the lines of this... $firstname = $_SESSION["your_data']["userid]? I only get one result from the query since it matches a username and password. What is the [index] do?

Comment: just print_r($_SESSION['your_data']): then give me result then i will help you how can you do it

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can store the result in session

Try this

```
session_start();
$data='';
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $user['userid'] = $rows['id'];
    $user['firstname'] = $rows['firstname'];
    $user['lastname'] = $rows['lastname'];
    $data[]=$user;

}
$_SESSION['Data'] = $data;
```

Comment: @Davo just try above  answer.

Comment: So if I use the code as you suggest, I simply call the variables on subsequent pages using the $user['firstname'] format or do I have to pull from the data array?

Comment: Yes you need to pull data from your DB and just push it to the `$user` variable,i used this to make the user data separated in session array.

Comment: Can you illustrate how I would place the session variable into a local variable on a future page (i.e. $userid = $user['userid'] OR $userid = $_SESSION['user'] OR  ???) Thank you - d

Comment: You can get session value like this
`foreach ($_SESSION['Data'] as $user){
    echo $user['userid']."<br>";
    echo $user['firstname']."<br>";
    echo $user['lastname']."<br>";
}`